# Destination table partition is empty but alter table switch still fails stating destination partition must be empty

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working with SQL Server 2008. I have two 100 partitioned tables of same structure, partition schema/function and same file group.

Table structure:

```
Create table source_table
(
     id int, 
     XmlData xml, 
     Partitionkey ([id]%(100)) As Persisted
)

Create table Destination_table
(
     id int, 
     XmlData xml, 
     Partitionkey ([id]%(100)) As Persisted
)
```

Requirement:

`Destination_table` has records but partition 23 is empty. I need to move partition 23 records from `Source_table` to `Destination_table`.

```
ALTER TABLE Source_table 
SWITCH partition 23 TO Destination_table partition 23
```

I get an error

> ALTER TABLE SWITCH failed. The target partition 23 of Destination_table must be empty.

The partition 23 of `destination_table` is already empty.

```
Select count(1) 
from destination_table
```

returns 0.

Then why do I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Had a confusion between partition value and partition Id. The partition value is 23 but the partition Id was 24 as the partition value started from 0 to 99 and the partition Id was 1 to 100.

So, the partition Id 24 worked for moving partition with value 23:

ALTER TABLE Source_table SWITCH partition 24 TO Destination_table partition 24

Answer (score 0):

This structure would work

```
Create table source_table
(
     id int, 
     XmlData xml, 
     Partitionkey ((([id] - 1) % (100)) + 1) As Persisted
)

Create table Destination_table
(
     id int, 
     XmlData xml, 
     Partitionkey ((([id] - 1) % (100)) + 1) As Persisted
)
```